# Reaction's side effect triggered only once if the mutation is inside another reaction's side effect

Tags: javascript, mobx

```
var obj = mobx.observable({ arr: [{}, {}, {}] });

mobx.reaction(() => obj.arr.map(x => x.foo), (newValue) => {
    console.log(newValue);
});

var trigger = mobx.observable({ flag: false });

mobx.reaction(() => trigger.flag, newValue => {
    obj.arr.forEach((x, i) => { x.foo = 'bar'; });
});

trigger.flag = true;
```

vs

```
var obj = mobx.observable({ arr: [{}, {}, {}] });

mobx.reaction(() => obj.arr.map(x => x.foo), (newValue) => {
    console.log(newValue);
});

obj.arr.forEach((x, i) => { x.foo = 'bar'; });
```

Please consider two pieces of code at above. 1st trigger the side effect with `console.log(newValue);` once only. Which I expected to be fired 3 times like how the 2nd example works.

Is this a bug? or by design?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is by design.

Basically, everything you do inside your `reaction` is automatically wrapped in `action`, and everything you do inside `action` is transactional which will batch all mutations and updates.

Reaction is roughly speaking sugar for `autorun(() => action(sideEffect)(expression))`

More: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html

Comment: Thank you @Danila. So how can I achieve sth like that in my question? e.g. pushing 3 items one by one into an observable array from an action. Cause I want know what every single item has been pushed into my observable array. (I don't think breaking synchronization like `setTimeout(() => { obsrvArr.push(x); }, 0)` is a good approach since it can be dangerous...)

Comment: Maybe use raw `autorun` for it?

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean

Comment: Never mind, it does not work anyway, just tried it :) Hm, not quite sure what else could help aside `setTimeout` hack

Comment: Hey @Danila. Thank you for your kindly help anyway!!